# Possible real values

Tags: quadratics

Set of all possible real values of a such that the inequality $(x-(a-1))(x-(a^2+2))<0$ holds for all $x$ belongs to $(1,3)$ needs to be found.
I tried by putting $x=2$ in the inequality, but nothing good resulted.
I thought I would get the idea but it was not that easy.
Help me with it with any new idea and explain the mistake in mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

- Notice that $a^2+2 \ge a-1$ and $a^2+2$ and $a-1$ are the roots. We want $(1,3) \subseteq (a-1, a^2+2)$.
- Hence we want $ a-1 \le 1 $ and $a^2+2 \ge 3$.

Comment: X belongs to (1,3)

Comment: sorry, I think wrongly just now. updated my guide.